# Top Bar breakpoint in foundation 5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, breakpoints

I tried the break point in 5.5.2 and was pretty easily accomplished just by changing the width in 3 instances as follow:

```
meta.foundation-mq-topbar {
  font-family: "/only screen and (min-width:64.063em/";
  width: 64.063em;
}


@media only screen and (min-width: 64.063em) {
  .top-bar {
    background: #333333;
    *zoom: 1;
    overflow: visible;
  }
```

the only problem I'm facing is the main menu (parent link) of the drop down is not visible (once you click, it only shows the dropdown part not the main link) when it comes to toggle menu, unless you reach the actual break point ie. 40.063 em. Should I need to make any change in javascript?

Thanks for helping me!!

Answer (score 0):

I've done a little more research and found the fix. All you have to do is go to [js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js]
line number 368 change "show-for-small" to "show-for-medium-down".

Following is the code for you:

```
if (settings.mobile_show_parent_link == true && url) {
            $titleLi = $('<li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></h5></li><li class="parent-link show-for-medium-down"><a class="parent-link js-generated" href="' + url + '">' + $link.html() +'</a></li>');
          } else {
            $titleLi = $('<li class="title back js-generated"><h5><a href="javascript:void(0)"></a></h5>');
          }
```

Then at the very bottom of your html file, where you are calling other js files, call topbar.js by adding following line

```
<script src="js/foundation/foundation.topbar.js"></script>
```

You can even make this work just by making the above mentioned change in js/foundation.min.js